# PARSE_DATETIME from string returns letter T in between date and time

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

**I want to convert the string to DateTime.**

My strings look like this:

```
19.03.2020 08:14:13
09.07.2020 07:32:39
```

I used these queries:

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', Date) AS NF_spent_date,
```

and

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%d.%m.%Y %T', Date) AS NF_spent_date,
```

but the result in both cases is

```
2020-03-19T08:14:13
2020-07-09T07:32:39
```

How can I avoid the T letter in the output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Google BigQuery displays DATETIME values. You can use PARSE_TIMESTAMP to convert to TIMESTAMP instead which is displayed without `T` but with `UTC` at the end:

```
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', '19.03.2020 08:14:13') AS NF_spent_date
```

[image]